# Refer to header value in payload validation schema in joi

Tags: validation, joi

I need to validate the payload in request body based on a key's value in request header. I have following route configured with joi schema,

```
//Route
routes.push({
        config: {
            validate: validatePostRequest(logger),
        },
        handler: controller.handlePost,
        method: "POST",
        path: "/post",
    });

//joi schema
public validatePostRequest = (logger: any): any => {
        return {
            failAction(request, reply, error) {
                console.log('joi error', error);
                //handle fail and return error
                return error;
            },
            headers: Joi.object({
                'x-some-key': Joi.string().optional(),
            }).unknown(true),
            payload: Joi.when(Joi.ref('/headers.x-some-key'), 
                { 
                    is: 'cond 1',
                    then: Joi.object({                        
                        dob: Joi.date().required()                        
                    }),
                    otherwise: Joi.object({
                        recipientFirstName: Joi.string().max(60).required()
                    }) 
                }
            )
        };
    }
```

In above code I would like to check the value of header x-some-key and then based on it decide the payload schema.
For some reason I am not able to achieve that with above code, is there any other way to achieve the same

Answer (score 0):

You can reach headers value with `$` like below. `/` is just for reach siblings field

```
Joi.ref('$headers.x-some-key')
```